# Rails Acts As Votable Ajax Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the Acts As Votable gem working in a social app I am developing and I am trying to get it to work via ajax so the page does not refresh, causing the reader to lose their place.

If I refresh the page the vote went through but I'm getting the following error and I don't understand what it means, or how to fix it:

```
Template is missing

Missing template posts/upvote, application/upvote with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

In my Posts Controller:

```
def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.liked_by current_user
end
```

My my view:

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(post), class: "like", method: :put, :remote => true do %>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" aria-label="Left Align">
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Mark Voted For
    | <%= post.get_upvotes.size %>
   </button>
<% end %>
```

At the bottom of my view (for now):

```
<script>
$('.like')
 .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
 .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
 .on('ajax:error', function () { $(this).after('<div class="error">There was an issue.</div>'); })
 .on('ajax:success', function (data) { $(this).html(data.count); });
</script>
```

My routes:

```
resources :posts, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
   member do
     put 'like' => 'posts#upvote' 
   end
end
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every controller action in rails should either redirect or render something. If you don't explicitly do either of those, rails tries to render a template that matches the controller and action names, in this case `app/views/posts/upvote.format`.

If you want to render nothing (which it seems like you do right now) add `render nothing: true` to the end of the `upvote` method. Otherwise, you would usually have a `app/views/posts/upvote.js` template to render that would update your view with the new vote total.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `posts/upvote.js.erb` as the message error suggests.